# Array.splice() seems to sometimes splice the last index and other times splice only up to (but not including) the last index

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

[My code](https://script.google.com/home/projects/1rHqRIxycUqbyo6TvOC9ySjD53LSH-9BPwOAMQ8GFJVUCMOKTh6XIqLHT/edit?usp=sharing) && [my Spreadsheet with the data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N8cLlFI9mRGgfYqcLNzwuzkmAOepf0itbS4N5GLqkEI/edit?usp=sharing) (not necessary to understand my problem, just a visualization)

---

I have an **'inventory'** array of 90 objects, divided in 3 categories:

- Category 1 | *1 item*;
- Category 2 | *53 items*;
- Category 3 | *36 items*.

I need to remove all items of Category 2 and 3, and get an array with the data that has been removed for each category (in the example code, I'm calling this array **'dataToRemove'**). For that, I am using the following `Array.forEach()` loop:

```
categoriesToRemove.forEach(function(category){

    let dataToRemove = inventory.filter(row=>row[5]==category);

    let startSplicing = inventory.findIndex(r=>r[5]==category)
    let endSplicing = inventory.lastRowWhere(category,5) //this is a custom function, more details below

    inventory.splice(startSplicing, endSplicing);

  });
```

This piece of code above works just fine when I try to remove these two Categories.

But if I first remove the one item that has 'Category 1' from the **'inventory'** array, trying to remove Category 2 and Category 3 (which should yield an empty array) instead returns an array with one 'Category 2' item still remaining:
[image: As you can see, it should remove 53 items of 'Category 2', but it only removes 52]

I do not understand what changed from the previous example to this one that would lead `Array.splice()` to simply refuse to splice one item. As far as I can see, my custom function is not to blame, but here it is anyways:

```
function lastRowWhere(condition,i,array){
      /*  searches an array from end to begginning and returns the last 
      ;   index of the array where the condition is met. */

      let helper, a=array.slice().reverse(), l=a.length;

      a.forEach(function(row,index){
        
        if (row[i]==condition){
          
          helper==undefined?
            
            helper=index
            :
            index=l-1
        
        }

      });

      let output = helper==undefined?(0):(l-helper-1)
      return output
    }
    Array.prototype.lastRowWhere = function(c,i){return lastRowWhere(c,i,this)};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will also say I'm sorry if there are any stupid mistakes in the code, I'm a beginner, and any feedback regarding any of those would be very welcome as well.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you possibly confusing `splice` and `slice`?

Comment: Hello @LaytonGB, in what part of the code do you mean that? If you mean in general, no, I do mean to `splice` items from the **inventory** array (as in, remove them). `slice()`, as far as I understand, simply returns a copy of a section of the array.

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: @Cooper, hey man, thanks for the link, but I always check W3 Schools and MDN before asking stuff here! I've reread it nonetheless and I still think I am missing what is causing this whole situation. Can you explain it to me in plain terms?